# Storing an Array of Strings(const char* stringlist[3])

Tags: c++, string, struct, char

I have an array of strings that I would like to copy into a struct member  for use in the program...

here is what i have as a string array declaration:

```
const char *stringArray[3] = {"my", "string", "array"};
```

How can I copy the data into a struct?

Comment: Modify the language tag, if it isn't `C`.

Comment: You're very vague about what you're trying to do. Do you want pointers to these strings in the struct, so you can access the strings but not modify them? Do you want copies in the struct so you can modify them? Do you need additional memory allocates so the struct can hold larger strings?

Comment: yes, I would like to point to the strings...I don't need to modify them/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct MyStruct {
  std::vector<std::string> strings;
};

MyStruct my_struct;
const char *stringArray[3] = {"my","string","array"};
for (int i=0; i!=3; ++i) {
  my_struct.strings.push_back(stringArray[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
struct foo {
   std::string fooStr;  // const std::string fooStr;
};

const char *stringArray[3] = {"my", "string", "array"};

foo obj;
obj.fooStr = stringArray[0];
```

If you don't wish to modify the member variables - then `const` qualify the member variable and do -

```
foo obj = { stringArray[0] };
```